# absolute positioning image in a div causing all content behind it to overlap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position, absolute

I am using twitter bootstrap, and I have the following code:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <img src="img/map.jpg" id="map" />
        <a id="modal-786791" href="#modal-container-786791" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal"><img src="img/pin.png"/></a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#map{
    position: absolute;
}

#modal-786791 img{
    position:relative;
}
```

I need to put the pin on top of the map. So I positioned the map absolutely and the pin relatively.
The problem is that when I put `#map` in an absolute positioning, all the content that follows the parent div is overlapping it. Here is a screenshot to show you the result:

[image]

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Applying `position:absolute` takes the element out of the normal flow, Hence when you absolutely position the map, the static elements following it will act like the map isn't there at all.

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to the relative **parent**. In the current markup, `#map` is not a parent of the pin, but a sibling, So add an `id` to the `<div>` containing it, for example

HTML

```
<div class="row clearfix">
<div id='mapContainer' class="col-md-12 column">
    <img src="img/map.jpg" id="map" />
    <a id="modal-786791" href="#modal-container-786791" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal"><img src="img/pin.png"/></a> 
</div>
```

Then you can position the container as relative (*So that it'll stay in normal flow*) and pin as absolute.

```
#mapContainer{
 position:relative;
}
#modal-786791 img{
 position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, here is the result: http://imgur.com/OhuMh8Y
the pin i am using is the red one, not the pink one. It is now almost hiding behind the pictures below it, you can see the tip of it.

Comment: Unfortunately that site is blocked in my network… wouldn't make much difference since we can't inspect the image… can you provide an online link to, or a demo such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating this..?

Comment: @user3666936 i think i got it, check the updated answer.

Comment: still not working. And it's weird because I know that it should be as you said, but it is not working!

Comment: @user3666936 probably because bootstrap is overriding stuff… try adding `!important`, but that might intern break bootstraps stuff..!

Comment: @user3666936, can you give dimensions of your images ? There just these 2 lines of css for #mapContainer and img ? I doubt that bootstrap override id rules.

Comment: yea I actually gave width:100% to map, and width: 30px to the pin. Height is auto.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use z-index:99999; in de css